# Google map showing as grey screen in web app

Tags: html, flutter, firebase, google-maps, firebase-hosting

I'm hosting my flutter web app on firebase and when I open the page with a map the page is completely grey. All the other pages work fine but not the map one.
This is my index.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="ReDue">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="redue">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>redue</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script  src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="main.dart.js" defer></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*****"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        }
      }).then(function(engineInitializer) {
        return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
      }).then(function(appRunner) {
        return appRunner.runApp();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I have the api key in there. It should also be noted that when I hosted the app locally using flutter webserver run the map worked. Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: Do you have any error codes? The community can't really know at this point what's wrong, but I think it would be better for you to contact the technical support team for them to be able to look into your account, since this could be an API key restriction issue. Here's the link to make things easier for you: https://developers.google.com/maps/support#creating-a-support-case

Comment: If you are using google_maps_flutter package, it does not support web.